# Textbook on Abstract Data Types

Tags: books, abstract-data-types

I'm looking for a textbook or reference material to learn about the theory of abstract data types, the ways in which they are specified (axiomatic specification vs abstract model), imperative vs functional definitions, etc.

I'm looking for a theoretical book that gives a good introduction to how they are discussed and defined in contemporary CS research.

Papers or course notes are welcome as well. Thank you.

Comment: I think you are asking about different things. Most books (including standard ones, like CLRS) cover imperative definitions (i.e. the ones which modify the DS itself). Pure functional definitions (which work with immutable DS and return a new DS after each operation, preserving the old DS) can often be obtained from empirical ones: e.g. it's trivial for stack and tree (non-trivial for queue and dequeue though), and I didn't see them in books. I think people care about axiomatic/abstract stuff in different context, i.e. program verification. Check e.g. https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/

Comment: @Dmitry I have a basic understanding of what an ADT is--a mathematical model for a data type (e.g. the specification of Queue in some language-independent way) that explains its behavior in programs. But from the Wikipedia page on them, I am gathering that is more than one way to go about defining the behavior of an ADT (e.g. axiomatic semantics vs abstract model). I would like reference material that explains these various ways of formally specifying the behavior of ADTs and why one would choose one over another.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/48509/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/136030/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).